# Mocking HttpResponse.StatusCode with AutoFixture and Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

I am using [AutoFixture as an auto-mocking container](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/08/19/AutoFixtureasanauto-mockingcontainer/) and want to mock an `HttpResponse` so that I can verify that a specific `StatusCode` has been set. However, I am getting a `NotImplementedException` when I call `SetupSet`:

```
var response = _fixture.Freeze<Mock<HttpResponseBase>>();
response
    .SetupSet(x => x.StatusCode = It.IsAny<int>());
```

If I just use a new Mock of `HttpResponseBase`, I get no exception, but then I would have to write a `FreezeMoq` extension method as explained in Mark Seemann's [Freezing mocks](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/03/27/Freezingmocks/) blog post.

What is AutoFixture doing that means I cannot setup a set on virtual property where the base class throws a `NotImplementedException`, but can when just using Moq?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Moq behaves that way, and you can reproduce the behaviour without AutoFixture:

```
[Fact]
public void ReducedRepro()
{
    var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
    response.CallBase = true;
    Assert.Throws<NotImplementedException>(() =>
        response.SetupSet(x => x.StatusCode = It.IsAny<int>()));
}
```

The above test passes, demonstrating that Moq throws `NotImplementedException` in this case when you set `CallBase` to `true`, which is exactly what *AutoMoq* does.

In most cases, setting `CallBase` to true is the appropriate configuration for mocking base classes (it has no effect on interfaces), because it means that you can trust that a mocked class still has all default behaviour in place, unless you override virtual methods. This provides the advantage that you don't have to call `Setup` methods for all virtual methods, which would otherwise lead to brittle tests.

In this case, however, it leads to a failure, because `HttpResponseBase.StatusCode` is a virtual method that is 'implemented' by throwing `NotImplementedException` from both getter and setter. How that design decision ever made it past code review is beyond me.

You can work around it fairly easy by using `SetupProperty`:

```
[Fact]
public void Workaround()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
    var response = fixture.Freeze<Mock<HttpResponseBase>>();
    response.SetupProperty(x => x.StatusCode);
    response.Object.StatusCode = 42;
    Assert.Equal(42, response.Object.StatusCode);
}
```

This test passes, demonstrating that you can now assign and read values of the `StatusCode` property.

Comment: Thanks a million Mark! `SetupProperty` and `CallBase` are new to me, I've now learnt more about Moq as well as AutoFixture ;)